# Webpack warning "the request of a dependency is an expression" goes away using template strings instead of variables. How?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, requirejs, template-literals

I had a webpack warning in my nextjs dev server saying

`Critical dep: the request of a dependency is an expression`

This was because I imported some modules using variables, but the warning got away when i used template strings instead.

Original code that caused the warning to appear (using variables):

```js
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, file)
const module = require(filePath)
```

I understand the reason for this warning: webpack can't statically analyze and so unnecessarily bundles all possible modules.
To get rid of the warning I tried using template strings:

```js
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, file)
const module = require(`${filePath}`)
```

and this made the error go away but I am confused why. Webpack still doesn't know the filePath at build time as it is still dynamic, how does using template literals in place of just variables makes a difference. Won't webpack include the corresponding module in the final bundle and expect it to available at runtime?